# cpp generate a .lib and use it in another project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-libraries, facade, .lib

I have one project : mialsrtkOrientImage with one .h and one .cpp
and lot of dependencies "managed" with cmake.
I want to make a .lib of it
(it compile and create the .lib)

and now I want to use the .lib in another project OrientImageWrapper to have the class defined in the project mialsrtkOrientImage

I have this :
mialsrtkOrientImage.h:

```
#ifndef mialsrtkOrientImage_H
#define mialsrtkOrientImage_H

class MialOrientImage {

  public:

      //! default constructor
      MialOrientImage();

      //! default destructor
      ~MialOrientImage();

      std::string inputFile;
      std::string outputFile;
      std::string orientation;
      void reOrient(std::string inputFile, std::string outputFile, std::string orientation);

  private:
      int coucou;

};
#endif
```

and in the OrientImageWrapper:

```
#ifndef mialsrtkOrientImageWrapper_H
#define mialsrtkOrientImageWrapper_H

#include <string>

# define reOrientWrapper_EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)

class MialOrientImage;

class reOrientWrapper_EXPORT reOrientWrapper {

public:

    //! default constructor
    reOrientWrapper();

    //! default destructor
    ~reOrientWrapper();

    std::string inputFile;
    std::string outputFile;
    std::string orientation;
    void reOrient(std::string inputFile, std::string outputFile, std::string orientation);
    int test = 1;

private:
    MialOrientImage* wrap_MialOrientImage;

};
```

in the OrientImageWrapper.cpp I have:

```
#include "mialsrtkOrientImageWrapper.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void reOrientWrapper::reOrient(std::string inputFile, std::string outputFile, std::string orientation)
{
    std::cout << inputFile << outputFile << orientation << std::endl;
    wrap_MialOrientImage.reOrient(inputFile, outputFile, orientation);

}

reOrientWrapper::reOrientWrapper()
{
    std::cout << "construit" << std::endl;
}

reOrientWrapper::~reOrientWrapper()
{
    std::cout << "detruit" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    reOrientWrapper test;
    std::cout << test.test << std::endl;
    test.reOrient("plif", "plaf", "plouf");
    return 0;
}
```

in visual studio I put the folder having the .lib in configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directrories

I can see my .lib here: [image]

but when I want to compile the OrientImageWrapper I have this error:

> left of .reOrient must have class/struc/union, error code C2228

so it seems that there was a problem creating the class MialOrientImage from the .lib

How could I solve this?

Comment: You need to manage header files and library files separately. Just linking .lib won't make code compile.

Comment: what do you mean ? I don't want to include the mialsrtkOrientImage.h. 
it can have dependencies to other include. I want to make a kind of facade. generate a .lib, I used cmake and Target_link_libraries to many .h to generated it. and now I want to generate a wrapper using the .lib and avoid to have to link the wrapper to what I specified into target_link_libraries in the previous project

Comment: Including `mialsrtkOrientImage.h` to call `MialOrientImage::reOrient` or to use this class otherwise is mandatory. Without definition from that header file class is incomplete. Creating and linking a .lib does not make header file unnecessary.

Comment: I don't want to include mialsrtkOrientImage.h, this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: because I can't link the wrapper project to the whole libraries linked to mialsrtkOrientImage project

Comment: even if I add Including `mialsrtkOrientImage.h` in my wrapper.cpp I still get the same error. `wrap_MialOrientImage.reOrient` "left of .reOrient must have class/struc/union, error code C2228"

Comment: That is because `wrap_MialOrientImage` is a pointer. So it should be `wrap_MialOrientImage->reOrient`. If you don't won't to include `mialsrtkOrientImage.h` because it actually includes other headers then you will need to make an interface that does not include those other headers. Look for PImpl idiom.

Comment: If you don't add the header file, the new project will not see what is in the lib file.

Comment: thanks. I found the two following links very usefull on pimpl idiom:
https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/01/pimpl.html
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17536/Use-of-PIMPL-Design-Pattern